# NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate for date comparison

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, date, nspredicateeditor

I'm building an `NSPredicateEditor`, and I want the ability to do advanced date comparison.

I realize that I can build an `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate` with a `rightExpressionType` of `NSDateAttributeType`, but the predicates I want to build need to be much more advanced than that.

For example, I need to basic comparison like:

- `dateKeypath < aDate`
- `dateKeypath <= aDate`
- `dateKeypath = aDate`
- `dateKeypath != aDate`
- `dateKeypath > aDate`
- `dateKeypath >= aDate`

These basic comparisons are quite easy to achieve, and I have these working.  However, I also need to do comparisons like:

- `dateKeypath isInTheLast n days` (or weeks, months, years)
- `dateKeypath isNotInTheLast n days` (or weeks, months, years)
- `dateKeypath between aDate and anotherDate`

How can I achieve these sorts of comparisons?  I understand that I'll need to create a custom `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate`, but I haven't found any clear documentation on how to achieve something like this.

**EDIT** 
Bonus points are available for also knowing how to make these comparisons a full date-time (year-month-day-hour-minute-second) comparison (as `NSDateAttributeType` only has year-month-day granularity).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In retrospect, this answer seems somewhat obvious:

I actually described *3* predicate editor row templates, not one.  The three templates are:

- `dateKeyPath [<, <=, =, >, >=, !=] [NSDatePicker]`
- `dateKeyPath [inTheLast, notInTheLast] [NSTextField] [NSPopUpButton]`
- `dateKeyPath [between] [NSDatePicker] "and" [NSDatePicker]`

If you build these three predicate editor row templates and give them to the predicateEditor, the editor will realize that they're all using the same `dateKeyPath`, and display then crunch all their operators into a single popup button.  It will then switch out the actual views to the right of the operator depending on which operator is selected.

**Edit**

For bonus points: you can modify the precision of the date pickers by overriding the `templateViews` method, retrieving the templateViews from `super`, and setting the `datePickerElements` on the appropriate pickers.

**Edit 24 Nov 2010**

For anyone who comes across this again, I've written a couple blog posts on creating custom `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplates`:

- [Creating a simple `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate`](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1646098126/creating-a-simple-nspredicateeditorrowtemplate)
- [Creating an advanced `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate`](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1677163679/creating-an-advanced-nspredicateeditorrowtemplate) (this one shows how to do the `inTheLast` and `inTheNext` row template)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the second predicate template will work as expected. The problem is that you need a relative date - a date that is evaluated relative to the current date.

I have implemented such a predicate editor template (with all the associated code) based on some code (and advice) from an Apple engineer. If anyone is interested I can provide the details, etc. My implementation is quite involved.

Comment: Yeah, I eventually worked that as well. Shoot me an email with what you came up with! I'd love to share notes with you.

Comment: Sure. I'm a StackOverflow newbie. How do I email you?

Comment: my profile has a link to my homepage, which has an email form.